# Detecting changes on database table column status

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am having a project in Laravel. In database I have a status column, which shows if exam is started or not. I had an idea in the waiting room checking every single second if the status was changed or not, if changed to 1, when the exam starts, but I am so new to Laravel and everything else, that I even don't get the main idea how I could do this, I don't ask for any code, just for the lead, to move on. yeah, hope someones gets me. Thanks if someone answers me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about leveraging Observers? Also instead of having a status boolean, you could take a similar approach that Laravel has done for soft deletes and set exam_started_at. This way you can also keep track of time stamp and state all in one column. Also, observers are immediate rather than pushing them into a queue. Then generate a websocket event that can report back to your front end, if needed.

check out Laravel observer and soft delete documentation.

Comment: watch out with observers, there is a reported issue when you add many objects via factories they get stuck returning the same value, will update with the issue link

Comment: @jmvcollaborator how is it not potentially a better approach and I think you may be assuming that the OP is using a specific version? However, I get it because I used a link with Laravel v9, but there is no way to pass their documentation given you don't know the version. Not knowing that there was a current issue I think before stating that comment you should have asked the OP their question and only because you may scare people away from using a potentially better design pattern. Thinking in concepts or design vs something specific to a language version that has an issue. GTK tho thanks!

Comment: I also think that what @Skywarth's answer stated the same approach but did not leverage laravel's built-in Observers.

Comment: umm, im so confused now :D

Comment: Could you tell me more about websocket event?

Comment: Is it the right doc: laravel broadcasting?

Comment: And last question, will it work fine on externally hosted website? i mean posted online..

Comment: @Minij4 Yes two of your last two questions. I redacted/edited on being specific, based on jmvcollaborator comment which was good information. However, I didn't have the time to ask you for those that information.

Answer (score 0):

Check about laravel cron jobs. You will need a class implementing ShouldQueue interface and using Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
With regards to the storage of the jobs i do recommend Redis or SQS.
In order to keep monitoring the queue in production think about installing supervisor.
Further information here: [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues)

Comment: Thanks a lot, cause I was wasting my time with such a thing like events and so on. So, rll needed for the help...

Comment: I would be willing to bet @EmJa the events design pattern probably fits your use case more because it is probably easier to setup in a scalabale PaaS like AWS, GCP, etc. Utilizing a service like pusher abstracts that work out and all you have to worry about is routing versus having to figure out how to scale this stuff the correct way that is optimized and cost-effective without creating complexity that can be quite complicated. I only say that because if you think eventing was a waste of time or confusing, just wait till you have to deal with that.

Comment: keep it simple man, you are mixing up things

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I don't totally understand what you mean. However, I actually think you might be overcomplicating it and also never asked the OP about their experience with these other tools and how they are deploying. However, my comment above was more about keeping it simple. You just have to setup up Pusher on a free account, maybe some routing, and given that you do not have the OP's full end use case it keeps it pretty simple.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator, I'm confused by what you mean, again?

Answer (score 0):

Your plan can work, it is called [polling](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/polling-in-javascript-ab2d6378705a?gi=3bd797af4897).

Basically, you will want to call

```
setInterval(function() {
    //your code here
}, 1000);
```

`setInterval` is a function that receives two parameter. The first is a callback function, that will periodically be executed and the second is the length of the period in milliseconds (1000 milliseconds is a second).

Now, you will need to implement your callback function (Javascript, of course) to send an [AJAX request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to a Laravel action. You will need to look into `XMLHttpRequest` and its usages, or you can use some libraries to simplify your task, like jQuery or Axios.

On Laravel's side you will need to implement an action and a Route for it. (read this: https://appdividend.com/2022/01/22/laravel-ajax/)

Your Laravel will need to load data from your database, you can use Eloquent for this purpose or raw queries and then respond the POST request with the result.

Now, in your Javascript at the AJAX request's code you will need to have a callback function (yes, a callback inside a callback) which will handle the response and the the changes.

Comment: ops missed the javascript part, good response wondering if he is really talking about javascript

Comment: @jmvcollaborator your answer (particularly the cron part) paired with push notifications/WebSockets can work. Upvoted.

Comment: @LajosArpad Why even if the OP wanted to do this here would you want to leverage a polling mechanism when laravel's websockets can do that?

Answer (score -1):

I know you specified "when the column on db changes..." but if it's not a strict-requirement you might want to consider implementing event-based architecture. Laravel has support for model events, which essentially allows you to run certain assertions and controls when a model created, updated, deleted etc.

```
class Exam extends Model
 protected static function booted()
 {
    static::updated(function ($exam) {
       if($exam->status=='your-desired-status'){
          //your actions
       }
       //you can even in cooperate change controls
       if ($exam->isDirty('status')){
          //means status column changed


       });
}

}
```

Of course this solution applies only if Database in question is in Laravel's reach. If database data changes outside the Laravel application these event listeners won't help at all.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but these events fire up just in that page where the model changes ?

Comment: No, it's global. So once you define it, it doesn't matter where you update/create/delete the model this event will fire.

Comment: Why not just use observers @Skywarth?

Comment: @AlexMac It can be done as well, very similar concept. Gave this example since it's so simple for OP to implement and see if it fits their need.